# ExpressJs + Passport.js + MySQL Authentication

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, passport.js

whenever i am trying to register any user through localhost its not creating the database i have tired to run the schema.sql file in mysql its working fine but after that also i am not able to register. i have given my entire code so can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
 package.json
    {
      "name": "passport_mysql_express_auth",
      "description": "ExpressJs + Passport.js + MySQL Authentication",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "author": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt-nodejs": "*",
        "body-parser": "*",
        "bookshelf": "0.5",
        "cookie-parser": "*",
        "ejs": "*",
        "express": "4.x",
        "express-session": "*",
        "knex": "^0.10.0",
        "mariasql": "^0.2.6",
        "mysql": "*",
        "passport": "*",
        "passport-local": "*"
      }
    }
```

---

```
App.js
// vendor libraries
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// custom libraries
// routes
var route = require('./route');
// model
var Model = require('./model');

var app = express();

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
   new Model.User({username: username}).fetch().then(function(data) {
      var user = data;
      if(user === null) {
         return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
      } else {
         user = data.toJSON();
         if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
         } else {
            return done(null, user);
         }
      }
   });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
   new Model.User({username: username}).fetch().then(function(user) {
      done(null, user);
   });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(session({secret: 'secret strategic xxzzz code'}));
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret strategic xxzzz code', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// GET
app.get('/', route.index);

// signin
// GET
app.get('/signin', route.signIn);
// POST
app.post('/signin', route.signInPost);

// signup
// GET
app.get('/signup', route.signUp);
// POST
app.post('/signup', route.signUpPost);

// logout
// GET
app.get('/signout', route.signOut);


// 404 not found
app.use(route.notFound404);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(err) {
   if(err) throw err;

   var message = 'Server is running @ http://localhost:' + server.address().port;
   console.log(message);
});
```

---

```
db.js
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf');

var config = {
   host: 'localhost',  
   port:'3307',// your host
   user: 'root', // your database user
   password: 'yourpassword', // your database password
   database: 'dbUsers',
   charset: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'
};

var DB = Bookshelf.initialize({
   client: 'mysql', 
   connection: config
});

module.exports.DB = DB;
```

---

```
model.js

var DB = require('./db').DB;

var User = DB.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'tblUsers',
   idAttribute: 'userId'
});

module.exports = {
   User: User
};
```

---

```
route.js

// vendor library
var passport = require('passport');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// custom library
// model
var Model = require('./model');

// index
var index = function(req, res, next) {
   if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.redirect('/signin');
   } else {

      var user = req.user;

      if(user !== undefined) {
         user = user.toJSON();
      }
      res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: user});
   }
};

// sign in
// GET
var signIn = function(req, res, next) {
   if(req.isAuthenticated()) res.redirect('/');
   res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In'});
};

// sign in
// POST
var signInPost = function(req, res, next) {
   passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                          failureRedirect: '/signin'}, function(err, user, info) {
      if(err) {
         return res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In', errorMessage: err.message});
      } 

      if(!user) {
         return res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In', errorMessage: info.message});
      }
      return req.logIn(user, function(err) {
         if(err) {
            return res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In', errorMessage: err.message});
         } else {
            return res.redirect('/');
         }
      });
   })(req, res, next);
};

// sign up
// GET
var signUp = function(req, res, next) {
   if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.redirect('/');
   } else {
      res.render('signup', {title: 'Sign Up'});
   }
};

// sign up
// POST
var signUpPost = function(req, res, next) {
   var user = req.body;
   var usernamePromise = null;
   usernamePromise = new Model.User({username: user.username}).fetch();

   return usernamePromise.then(function(model) {
      if(model) {
         res.render('signup', {title: 'signup', errorMessage: 'username already exists'});
      } else {

         var password = user.password;
         var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);

         var signUpUser = new Model.User({username: user.username, password: hash});

         signUpUser.save().then(function(model) {
            // sign in the newly registered user
            signInPost(req, res, next);
         });    
      }
   });
};

// sign out
var signOut = function(req, res, next) {
   if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      notFound404(req, res, next);
   } else {
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/signin');
   }
};

// 404 not found
var notFound404 = function(req, res, next) {
   res.status(404);
   res.render('404', {title: '404 Not Found'});
};

// export functions

// index
module.exports.index = index;

// sigin in
// GET
module.exports.signIn = signIn;
// POST
module.exports.signInPost = signInPost;

// sign up
// GET
module.exports.signUp = signUp;
// POST
module.exports.signUpPost = signUpPost;

// sign out
module.exports.signOut = signOut;

// 404 not found
module.exports.notFound404 = notFound404;
```

---

```
schema.sql
drop database if exists dbUsers;

create database if not exists dbUsers;

use dbUsers;

drop table if exists tblUsers;

create table if not exists tblUsers(
   userId integer primary key auto_increment,
   username varchar(100) unique,
   password varchar(100)
)engine=innodb;
```

---

```
index.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>
         Welcome <strong><%= user.username %></strong>
         <a href="/signout" title="sign out">sign out</a>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

```
signin.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Sign In Form</h2>
      <form method="post" action="/signin">

         <% if(typeof(errorMessage) !== 'undefined') {%>
            <span><%= errorMessage %></span>
         <% } %>
         <p>
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
               placeholder="username" required="true"/>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password"
               placeholder="password" required="true"/>
         </p>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="sign in"/> 
            <a href="/signup" title="register">register</a>
         </p>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

```
signup.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Register Form</h2>
      <form method="post" action="/signup">
         <% if(typeof(errorMessage) !== 'undefined') {%>
         <span><%= errorMessage %></span>
         <% } %>
         <p>
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
               placeholder="username" required="true"/>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password"
               placeholder="password" required="true"/>
         </p>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" value="register"/>
            <a href="/signin" title="sign in">sign in</a>
         </p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean data is not going in the database?

Comment: so how to fix this ?have u run the code

Comment: whats the error are you getting and can you add your package.json?

Comment: actually i am not getting any error after entering the userid and password the page is loading only it is not adding the vale in db neither it is going to another page...

Comment: There's way too much code here - do you expect someone to spend a day debugging your issue? You'll get far better answers if you spend some time yourself reducing it to identify the specific problem; doing so is also likely to lead you to the answer without needing help. Read about [minimal, complete and verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: man actually i got this code from github and done some modification.as i am complete new to nodejs i am not able to do user authentication with mysql/mariasql.so if have done the code then plz give so that i can learn and know all the error in my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bookself` works well with `knex` so install `knex` first by using the below command

```
npm install --save knex
```

once installed change your `db.js` file as below

```
    var knex = require('knex')({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'deen',
            password: 'deen',
            database: 'lttp',
            charset  : 'utf8'
        }
    });

    var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

    module.exports.DB = Bookshelf;
```

inside your `package.json` change the `Bookself` version to `*`. your `package.json` should have the below dependency list.

```
 {
      "name": "passport_mysql_express_auth",
      "description": "ExpressJs + Passport.js + MySQL Authentication",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "author": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt-nodejs": "*",
        "body-parser": "*",
        "bookshelf": "*",
        "cookie-parser": "*",
        "ejs": "*",
        "express": "4.x",
        "express-session": "*",
        "knex": "*",
        "mariasql": "^0.2.6",
        "mysql": "*",
        "passport": "*",
        "passport-local": "*"
      }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad to know.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!